# How do I make a subtable in Access in this situation?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, relationships

I'm aware that someone will see this and say "I'm sure there's already an answer to "how do I make a subtable", so this question is repetitive." Well, no answers seem to be relevant to THIS situation. Here goes:
I own a car business. I want to make a rolling list of costs associated with each car, to eventually be summed into "totalCosts".

I have table

```
ASSETS
     stock#, 
     make, 
     model, 
     purchase price, 
     totalCosts
```

and table

```
COSTS
     description, 
     cost (in $)
```

so I want the COSTS table to contain several costs like:

```
purchase price $2,000
paint $50
new tires $200
```

I can figure out how to sum the costs, but mainly I need to know how do I make the COSTS table to exist for each car or stock#. So each stock# would have its list of COSTS, which I would sum and insert into total costs.

The only solution I see now is to make a costs table that contains every cost with a stock # on the same line, but I would like to have a separate costs table for each stock #

Answer (score 0):

This is really the most basic related table you can make – quite much applies to near any database system.

You cost table will have

Id  - pk id (all tables should have this PK)
Asset ID   - standard long number column used to relate back to the assets table.

Item     (description of the cost (paint, tires, seat repair, etc. etc. etc.)
Cost     (the amount of the given item)

So you build a main form that is based on the assets, and then build a sub form that likely best setup of as a “repeating rows” or so called multiple items form (of which you drop into your main form, and thus the “costs” form becomes a sub-form of the assets.

So in effect, you attach each row of cost to a given single assets record. And access will “set” the Asset ID column for you automatic if you drop in the costs form as a sub form into the assets form.

The form will thus look something like this form:

[image]

In above, (a access application and a basic form I built in Access) I actually have “two” columns in which to select the “item” or “cost” type. I have sunglasses, but on the next row I could add tires, then paint, then whoever I want. Over time, you can add any kind of “new” cost item without having to create a new table or change the database structure.

If your design requires a “change” in the table structure for each new “thing” you enter, then you have the wrong design. Can you imagine an accounting package that you have to “stop” all the time and modify the software?

And then the real mess comes when you attempt to build a report. Once again, reports only work on pre-defined tables – you can “switch” tables on the fly for a report.

So any concept you have in regards to spreadsheets etc. must be tossed out of your mind. Computer information systems SIMPLY DO NOT WORK THAT WAY AND CANNOT WORK THAT WAY!

So keep in mind that Relational databases are NOT spreadsheets, and you don’t and CAN NOT adopt designs that require structure changes on the fly. Forms, reports, a query, and even computer code cannot function on tables that change for each record you enter – you MUST adopt a data model that reflects your current needs. That data model if done right can THEN be used for very complex accounting systems, ERP systems, or even a web store front that has 1000’s or even millions of different products. Such data models are designed first, and then the forms and user interface, the reports etc. are THEN created.

The same even goes for job costing. You might have liquids, labor costs, wall paper used in feet, paint used in gallons, and tiles used in meters. So just like an invoice system, job costing systems can handle “different” kinds of costs, and no table changes are required.

In above, we have an invoice like setup, and we can add as many things we want to a tour booking. (Tickets, jackets, books, skates, tires, paint, seats, and windows - whatever we want – we simply add a new row for whatever we need.

Think of any kind of “invoice” software you used – you can add as many items you want to that invoice.

A relational database does NOT support a whole new table for each new “cost” that you want to build – databases simple do not work this way. So you only (so far) really need a master table of the asset, and then the child table of “costs”.

You can’t create a whole new “cost” table for each asset as the built in tools in near any and all databases don’t support nor work with creating a new table for each new set of data you create.

And for ease of data entry, you could build a table of cost Items, so the user does not have to type in paint, tires etc., but choose that item from a drop down combo box.

So EVERY single example on the internet, every book, and every article that explains how to relate a master table to a child table is in fact 100% relevant and is how you HAVE to approach this problem.

Relational databases do not support creating of a whole new table for “one” new set of data, because such an approach cannot be used in reports nor does the query language support such a design.

Comment: I appreciate it! The explanation was very helpful, I understand the need for clean structure in a database, because once the date gets rolling you can't go back and switch up the structure. I think I didn't really understand how to make a "child table" to the "master table", hopefully this terminology will yield more fruitful google searches. Thanks again.